# perl - How to schedule a photo to Facebook page

Tags: facebook, perl, facebook-graph-api, schedule

Using [Facebook::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/~rizen/Facebook-Graph/lib/Facebook/Graph.pm) module I can schedule a simple text message to one of my pages. But, I want to schedule a photo instead of text message.

Here is the sample code that **post a scheduled text message** to my Facebook page. It will post "Hello World!", scheduled on 1 hour.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Facebook::Graph;

my $FB_PAGE_ID = 'FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID';

# Short-lived Page Token with permissions: manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions, public_profile
my $FB_PAGE_TOKEN = 'FACEBOOK_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN';

my $fb = Facebook::Graph->new;
$fb->access_token($FB_PAGE_TOKEN);

my $R = $fb->add_page_feed
    ->set_page_id($FB_PAGE_ID)
    ->set_message('Hello World!')
    ->set_scheduled_publish_time(time+3600)
    ->set_published('false')
    ->publish
    ->as_string;

print "\n$R\n\n";
```

Here is another sample code that **post a photo** to Facebook page, but without "schedule" feature.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Facebook::Graph;

my $FB_PAGE_ID = 'FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID';
my $FB_PAGE_TOKEN = 'FACEBOOK_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN';

my $fb = Facebook::Graph->new;
$fb->access_token($FB_PAGE_TOKEN);

my $R = $fb->add_photo($FB_PAGE_ID)
    ->set_source('sample_photo.jpg')
    ->publish
    ->as_string;

print "\n$R\n\n";
```

I am trying to figure out how to schedule a photo (instead of text message or link) to a Facebook page. Is there any other Perl module or something that can accomplish this?

Comment: Use the `at` command.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(Unix)